# Transformar linhas em colunas em SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo a seguinte Query:

```
SELECT distinct finmovem.num_transacao
       ,finempe.codigo_orgao 
       ,finempe.cod_reduzido 
       ,finempe.num_empenho 
       ,finempe.data_empenho 
       ,finempe.nome_fornecedor 
       ,finempe.valor_empenhado 
       ,finempe.valor_anulado 
       ,finempe.valor_pago 
       ,finempe.valor_liquidado 
       ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_liquidado as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_liquidar 
       ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_pago as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_pagar
       ,cast(orcdotac.sld_orc_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_orc_vinc as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_supl_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_esp_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_ext_ano as decimal(18,2)) - cast(orcdotac.sld_re_ano as decimal(18,2)) as saldo_dot_ant
       ,SUM(finmovem.valor_transacao ) tansacao
FROM finempe
INNER JOIN finmovem ON
    (finempe.num_empenho = finmovem.num_empenho) 
INNER JOIN orcdotac ON
    (finempe.cod_reduzido = orcdotac.cod_reduzido) 
WHERE finempe.codigo_tipo = 1 and finempe.codigo_orgao = 02 and finempe.data_empenho between '1-1-2002' and '31-12-2002' and finempe.cod_reduzido = 25
GROUP BY finmovem.num_transacao, finempe.codigo_orgao, finempe.cod_reduzido, finempe.num_empenho, finempe.data_empenho, finempe.nome_fornecedor, finempe.valor_empenhado, 
finempe.valor_anulado, finempe.valor_pago, finempe.valor_liquidado, orcdotac.sld_orc_ano, orcdotac.sld_orc_vinc, orcdotac.sld_supl_ano, orcdotac.sld_esp_ano, orcdotac.sld_ext_ano,
orcdotac.sld_re_ano   
ORDER BY finempe.cod_reduzido, finempe.num_empenho
```

Que me retorna o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o *num-transacao* e *transacao* virassem colunas ao invés de linhas,ou seja, para cada num_transacao ter uma coluna transacao correspondente, quais modificações deverão ser feitas? Quero somente uma linha para o num_empenho 11.

Comment: é diferente o problema

Comment: bem espero que isto te ajude. Faz o que tu necessitas. Se continuares com dúvidas diz. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: o problema pode ate ser diferente mas creio que adaptando a outra resosta podes ter a solução. Pois a solução completa creio ser dificil alguem lhe entregar

Comment: @Otto , não sei se vc concorda comigo, apesar de a dúvida ser a mesma e apenas apresentar uma variação acho válido não ser um duplicata, pois há diferenças e creio que irá ajudar mais do que o post que vc mencionou, tendo em vista que coloquei a resposta do que fiz aqui mesmo, o que acha? dê uma olhada aí, tá em SQL mais "cru", digamos assim

Comment: Duplicata por ser uma solução parecida, é muita sacanagem vir aqui e querer a solução completa para seu problema sendo que tem coisas parecidas, tudo precisa de uma adaptação para funcionar como voce quer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei as dicas dadas no post e cheguei na seguinte resposta:

```
SELECT num_empenho AS EMP, data_empenho AS DATA, nome_fornecedor AS FORNECEDOR, valor_empenhado AS EMPENHADO, valor_anulado AS ANULADO, [3] AS LIQ_PERIODO, valor_liquidado AS LIQUID_ACUM, [5] + [7] AS PAGO_PERIODO, valor_pago AS PAGO_ACUMUL
FROM (
      SELECT finmovem.num_transacao
       ,finmovem.valor_transacao
       ,finempe.codigo_orgao 
       ,finempe.cod_reduzido 
       ,finempe.num_empenho 
       ,finempe.data_empenho 
       ,finempe.nome_fornecedor 
       ,finempe.valor_empenhado 
       ,finempe.valor_anulado 
       ,finempe.valor_pago 
       ,finempe.valor_liquidado 
       ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_liquidado as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_liquidar 
       ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_pago as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_pagar
       ,cast(orcdotac.sld_orc_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_orc_vinc as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_supl_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_esp_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_ext_ano as decimal(18,2)) - cast(orcdotac.sld_re_ano as decimal(18,2)) as saldo_dot_ant     
FROM finmovem
LEFT JOIN finempe ON
    (finempe.num_empenho = finmovem.num_empenho) 
INNER JOIN orcdotac ON
    (finempe.cod_reduzido = orcdotac.cod_reduzido) 
WHERE finmovem.codigo_tipo = 1 and finmovem.codigo_orgao = 02 and finmovem.data_transacao between '1-1-2002' and '31-12-2002' and finempe.cod_reduzido = 25
GROUP BY finmovem.valor_transacao, finmovem.num_transacao, finempe.codigo_orgao, finempe.cod_reduzido, finempe.num_empenho, finempe.data_empenho, finempe.nome_fornecedor, finempe.valor_empenhado, 
finempe.valor_anulado, finempe.valor_pago, finempe.valor_liquidado, orcdotac.sld_orc_ano, orcdotac.sld_orc_vinc, orcdotac.sld_supl_ano, orcdotac.sld_esp_ano, orcdotac.sld_ext_ano,
orcdotac.sld_re_ano   
      ) sq 
PIVOT (SUM(sq.valor_transacao) FOR num_transacao IN ( [3], [5], [7])) AS pt
```

As quatro linhas geradas viraram essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito obrigado pelas dicas, galera!